# How can I create a client side cognito session from an AuthenticationResult?

Tags: javascript, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

The `AWS` object from the `aws-amplify` package allows a frontend application to start a cognito authentication flow by calling the `signIn` method.
This dispatches some traffic to the cognito servers, and ultimately if successful, returns
an `AuthenticationResult` object, whose values are set in the browser's local storage (or cookies, if configured to do so).

How can the local session be set using an `AuthenticationResult` object which was acquired elsewhere? (eg through the use of the `AdminInitiateAuth` method on the backend)

Answer (score -1):

If the backend shares origin with the frontend you can have a simple document that places the values in localstorage before redirecting back to your SPA.

Otherwise you are out of luck. OAuth is all about this exact issue: how to grant access to clients in a secure manner. Your SPA is one client, your backend is another.

Comment: How do I place the values in localstorage though? Is there any public API in the AWS SDK allowing me to do that?